Calling a function from Accessibility Service Activity
I have two activities, 1 being a Service Activity and the other a regular Activity. I have a function in the Service Activity(Button Service) called doAction() and I need it to be called in my regular activity(Review Activity).
The Code below is from the Button Service Activity
public class Button_Service extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

}


public void onInterrupt() {

}



public void doAction() {
  performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);

   
}


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
  } 
}

Below, I've tried calling the method doAction() in my regulary Activity(Review Activity) but getting the error "cannot resolve method 'doAction()' in 'Button_Service'.
Button_Service.doAction();

How can I get this issue fixed and working? The function is intended to trigger a Back Button Click Event.
